# CMOS IC Layout Recommendation for beginners

Tags: integrated-circuit

I really want to receive advice for books, materials, or advice to start CMOS layout for beginners.
Currently i have no idea. I really want to understand what happens if i place a certain thing in the layout.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117817/learning-pcb-layout-strategy?rq=1

Comment: No i don think its related to your link. I want to ask about CMOS layout. not PCB layout!

Comment: Designing the inside of a CMOS integrated circuit chip, not the printed circuit board, correct?

Comment: Not sure if this will get much attention as a question post, since it's a very broad question. May be better ask in chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Most CMOS IC [VLSI] textbooks will have some of this, at least the basics. Book recommendations are alas off topic here, as primarily opinion based. Google found the following theread as the 1st hit: http://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_good_books_on_CMOS_Layout_design

Comment: Here's a free lecture based on one of those books: http://cmosedu.com/videos/cmos1/ch15/ch15_15_1_video/ch15_15_1_video.html

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion (CMOS) layouting is something you don't learn from a book. You learn it in practice, while doing it. At University I worked on some gate-arrays so you only connect the metals, the transistors are already there. So when I got my degree I knew zip (nothing) about layouting. But I quickly picked it up in my first job.

Although I'm a circuit designer I often layout my own and other people's circuits. Also the specific rules and best practices depend on the process technology used.

If you're a student, I would not worry too much about layout. Just make sure you know how a transistor is build up, have some understanding what is going on physically inside a transistor. Then once you are required to make a layout, it will be easy for you to learn.